# Amazon EMR, Hue set password is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, hue

I set my password during initial access of Hue page. I logged out and tried login to the hue `Http://<"amazon emr url">:8888/accounts/login`

It says invalid username and password. Why I am facing this issue

Comment: The way you typed your password when you set it is different than what you're typing now. Reset your password.

Comment: Password remains the same. After entering the password I saved it in chrome by using save the password. How can I reset when I am not able to log in and there are no links to reset the password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorted out the issue, I am giving here the steps I followed. Created a super user and am able to login with the user I have created

```
cd /usr/lib/hue
sudo build/env/bin/hue  createsuperuser

Username (leave blank to use 'root'): <enter the super user name>
Email address: <your email id>
Password: <password with one upper case, number, and special character>
Password (again): 
Superuser created successfully.
```